# Make a div which contains slanted buttons wider than its parent

Tags: html, css

I want a navigation bar with three buttons. The buttons should have slanted edges on the two interior edges. For this I use `transform: skewX(-25deg);`. This leads to three parallelograms; not good. No problem, I'll make the three parallelograms wider than the window, then contain them in a div, center them, and use `overflow: hidden;` on the parent div.

This works great on Chrome and Firefox, but does not work on Safari. It seems that Safari forces the child div to scale down to the width of the parent div, leaving me with the three parallelograms.

For demonstration, the three button are blue, and the child's background is yellow. The yellow should not be visible. Any help in making this work in Safari would be appreciated.

```
<html>   
<body>     
    <div id="parent">  
        <div id="child">
            <div class="slantButton">Button 1</div>
            <div class="slantButton">Button 2</div>
            <div class="slantButton">Button 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<style>  
    #parent {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        height: 15vw;
        width: 100vw;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #child {
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        width: 120vw; 
        background-color: yellow;
    }

    .slantButton {
        transform: skewX(-25deg);
        width: 40vw;
        background-color: blue;
        border: 2px solid white;
    }   
</style>  
</html>
```

Comment: Add display: -webkit-flex;  for the display property

Comment: I did this in the two places where display is being used. It does not seem to resolve the problem

Comment: What version of safari are you testing this on? And pc or mac?

Comment: It might also be related to the use of viewport units for width and height http://codepen.io/partypete25/pen/VaLXxq

Comment: Testing on Safari 9.0.3 on OS X El Capitan 10.11.3. I've tried using % instead of vw and didn't see a change.